# How do I console log a $.get() methods response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, getjson

I am teaching myself how to call API's, and am learning about the `$.get()` method. For the past week I have been trying to figure out how this method works and console logging the response.

For example when I do `$.get'(http://api.fixer.io/latest')` how would I get the response from that using a `console.log` using a callback function?

Comment: How about reading [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)?

Comment: Basically, you're asking us for a getting started tutorial...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
$.get("http://api.fixer.io/latest", function( data ) {
    console.log(data)
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Thank you so much. I dunno why the API's site doesn't say to use the data keyword to call on it!

Comment: @Arenticus it... does... right at the top where it describes the syntax. `Type: Function( PlainObject data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )`

Comment: `data` isn't a keyword.  It's just the name of the parameter the api gives.  A parameter can be named anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.get'(http://api.fixer.io/latest', function( data ) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Source: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do it:

Using callback argument:

```
$.get("http://api.fixer.io/latest", function( data ) {
    console.log(data)
});
```

Using `done()` callback:

```
$.get("http://api.fixer.io/latest").done(function( data ) {
    console.log(data)
});
```

Using `then()` of returned promise:

```
$.get("http://api.fixer.io/latest").then(function( data ) {
    console.log(data)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass a `function` as a second argument and receive the response :

```
$.get('http://api.fixer.io/latest', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```